# Product or chain rule

Tags: derivatives

$f(x)=\frac{(y')^2}{x^3}$

Find $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$

I don't understand how to take this derivative properly. Can someone describe step by step?

Comment: You need to clarify. What is $y'$?

Comment: y' comes from the functional: $J(x, y')=\int_0^2 \frac{(y')^2}{x^3}dx$

Comment: If you're using the Euler-Lagrange equation, you should be working with $\partial / \partial y'$ not $\partial / \partial y$.

Comment: So you should probably disregard my 'answer', which I don't think makes any sense anyway.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes, I corrected the typo in the question. Still having trouble with this derivative.

Comment: Incidentally, do you need any help solving the differential equation?! :))

Comment: That would be useful, too - got the derivative and I know it must be equal to 0, but no idea how to solve it. Also, I have another calculus of variation question with a derivative/solution confusion and an open bounty if you are interested - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722753/function-extremal-calculus-of-variations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

damn it now that's all wrong... Try 2:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}\frac{(y')^2}{x^3}=\frac{2y'}{x^3}$$ and $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2y'}{x^3}\right)=\frac{2y''x^3-3x^2(2y')}{x^6}$$ I'll make you simplify since it got all messed up the first time :)